# Render component based of parameter in path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For my project I want to render a user's page at url.com/username .. if the username of the logged in user matches the parameter then it'll render their profile page. So in my router I have this route...

```
<Route path="/:username" exact component={/* Profile or User's Page */}>
```

I have other routes where the components are conditional and I use a ternary in the component, however in this case it would be based off the :username parameter. Is there a way to access that value within the component tag? Or should I have some sort of HOC in the component tag where I can compare the :username parameter to authenticated username and then return the Profile or UserPage component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the URL parameters using the component prop `match.params.:param`

```
<Route
  path="/:username"
  component={Component}
/>

const Component = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.username}</h3>
  </div>
);
```

If you want to access the parameter inside the `component` parameter, you could for example use an anonymous component (or just have a component especially for determining which subcomponent would be used).

```
<Route path="/:username" 
       component={({match} => {
         if(match.params.username == this.props.username) {
           return <SomeComponent />
         } else ...
       })} 
/>
```

Comment: I know I can access it within the component like that but I need to render different component's based off the param. I tried something similar to your answer with match.params.username == this.props.Username ? return ProfilePage : return UserPage but that doesn't workyt